# Angular 1.5 custom directive not being executed before native angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm in the process of migrating from Angular 1.2.17 to Angular 1.5.8 and, and i've noticed that a directive I've wrote is not being executed anymore before any other directives as it used to be the case with Angular 1.2.17. I've tried to set the priority at my directive level to 1500, even a very big value like 9999999999999999999 but no effect.

Any idea on how I can fix this problem?

Thanks

Sample code is available here: [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fx97pO0VOJeSWreZU5hk?p=preview)

```
var sample = here
```

To see how it worked in 1.2.x just change the angular version

Comment: Could you share some code? Recreate your situation using a fiddle if possible?

Comment: You can find the example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/fx97pO0VOJeSWreZU5hk?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a DOM event handler to cleanup the input, add a `$parser` to the `ng-model` controller to do the cleanup.

```
app.directive('nesCleanupInput', [function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 99999999999999999999999999999999999,
    link: function(scope, element,attrs,ngModel) {
      //USE $parsers pipeline
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function nesCleanup (value) {
        let cleanup = value.toUpperCase();
        element.val(cleanup);
        return cleanup;
      });
      /*
      //REMOVE DOM event handler
      element.on('change input keyup', function(event) {
        onChange (event);
      });
      */
});
```

The problem was that DOM event handler of the `input` directive was fighting the DOM event of the `nes-cleanup-input` directive. Using the `$parsers` pipeline avoids this problem.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/fhWqFFKNGHFrYOWeYrxd?p=preview).

From the Docs:

> ### $parsers
>
> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control reads value from the DOM. The functions are called in array order, each passing its return value through to the next. The last return value is forwarded to the `$validators` collection.
>
> Parsers are used to sanitize / convert the `$viewValue`.

-- [AngularJS ng-model Controller API Reference - $parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)

Comment: Thanks! this approach partially works, in the sense that it works as long as i'm not trying to add empty spaces in the input field or deleting stuff from the input field and then reading